# Detecting if an IEnumerable<T> is Grouped, I'm getting some crazy results when checking the types

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, igrouping

So I'm trying to figure out if some any random IEnumerable passed to my method has been grouped. The idea being that I'm going to handle grouped data differently. My problem is the `IGrouping<>` is a generic interface that doesn't implement a non-generic interface, and for whatever reason I can't test for it with `is` statements.

To test this out here is my sample code:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
            {1, "Prime" },
            {2, "Prime" },
            {3, "Prime" },
            {4, "Not" },
            {5, "Prime" },
            {6, "Not" },
            {7, "Prime" },
            {8, "Not" },
            {9, "Not" },
            {10, "Not" },
            {11, "Prime" }
        };
        var grouped = from d in dict
                      group d by d.Value into gd
                      select gd;
        Debug.WriteLine("IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>: {0}", grouped is IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>);
        Debug.WriteLine("IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>: {0}", grouped is IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>);
        Debug.WriteLine("IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, KeyValuePair<object, object>>: {0}", grouped is IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>>);
        Debug.WriteLine("IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>: {0}", grouped is IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>>);
        Debug.WriteLine("IEnumerable<object>: {0}", grouped is IEnumerable<object>);
```

Output is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>: True
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>: True
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, KeyValuePair<object, object>>: False
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>: False
IEnumerable<object>: True
```

So it seems that unless I know the type of the values being grouped, I can't test to see if it's grouped? Is this a bug in the .Net Framework?

How are the results above even possible?

---

**EDIT: Jon Skeet's answer was dead on... As a courtesy to anyone else that find themselves here with the same difficulty I had, the following code did the job of checking to see if an IEnumerable was grouped or not (based off of Mr. Skeet's fancy-ass idea of using the dynamic keyword):**

```
    public static bool IsGrouped (dynamic test) {
        return CheckGrouping(test);
    }
    static bool CheckGrouping(object o ) {
        return false;
    }
    static bool CheckGrouping<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> grouping) {
        return true;
    }
```

Assuming the code is the same as above:

```
IsGrouped(dict); //false
IsGrouped(grouped); //true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The results are not just possible but *expected* under .NET 4 - in .NET 3.5, the final result would be False due to the lack of generic variance.

While [`IGrouping<out TKey, out TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) is covariant in both `TKey` and `TValue`, [`KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is a struct, and therefore cannot be used in a covariant manner.

So an `IGrouping<string, string>` is an `IGrouping<object, object>`, but an `IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>` is not.

This is *not* a bug in the framework. As for how to find out whether something implements `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` for some `TKey, TValue` pair, you could either work quite hard yourself, or using `dynamic` to try to help:

```
// Code as before...
dynamic dyn = grouped;
ShowGrouping(dyn);

private static void ShowGrouping<TKey, TValue>
   (IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> grouping)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TKey = {0}, TValue = {1}", typeof(TKey), typeof(TValue));
}

private static void ShowGrouping(object notGrouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a grouping");
}
```

Note that this certainly *isn't* foolproof - but it may be good enough for what you need.

Comment: Thanks! The first thing I attempted was actually an extension method for IEnumerable<T> for grouped or not grouped, which didn't really work. I didn't think to use the dynamic keyword. I realized it was an issue with KVP, strings, and ints being structs while I was playing with it and talking with a coworker.

Comment: @blesh: `string` isn't a struct, it's a class.

Comment: Thank you again! I've edited my question to include how I solved my particular issue using your super-clever use of the dynamic keyword. It's honestly the first time I've had a reason to use it, oddly enough.

Comment: +1 Mr. Skeet... you're correct that String is not a struct. That was me typing in a hurry more than anything.

Comment: Is there any reason why you could not use `if (typeof(grouped).FullName.StartsWith("System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable")) {...}`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I assume you mean `grouped.GetType()`... but basically this is brittle: 1) it assumes there are no other types starting with that name; 2) it assumes an *implementation detail* that grouping will use `GroupedEnumerable`, which isn't even a public type. I'm generally wary of code that uses type names instead of the types themselves to determine anything.